# Entity Framework Database.Exist() returning always true

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am using sql server credentials to connect using sql server management studio and getting error, that's **OK** because database doesn't exist

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to **Server IP **.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Logon failed for login **'USERID'** due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?
ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=17892&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]

But entity framework Database.Exists() always return true 
[image]

Why ?

Comment: What is your `connectionString`? Its probably pointing to master.

Comment: @SajalS , i have credentials for different database server and it's working fine. It's not related with connectionString.

Comment: Did you create a logon trigger and then drop/re-create the database?  Can you log into the database in Management Studio?  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/27/sql-server-fix-error-17892-logon-failed-for-login-due-to-trigger-execution-changed-database-context-to-master/